# What are the characteristics of a "tsundere"?

Tags: tropes

Although this question might be a naive thing to ask, I believe that I would get an much detailed answer to this question keeping in mind all my simple questions answered wonderfully by people in the past. I read the wiki page on Tsundere but there's not much, I understand the broad definition where a person has a combative attitude towards a particular protagonist in any anime. What I am looking for, is an all-encompassing criteria/concept of a 'tsundere' and the highlights of their social behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From  [KnowYourMeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/tsundere)

> The word tsundere is a portmanteau of the japanese terms **tsun-tsun** (turning away in disgust) and **dere-dere** (lovey-dovey feelings).

Typically *tsundere* characters are characters who *aren't honest with themselves* about loving another character. They'll often say things like;

"It's not as if it I did that for you, dummy - don't get the wrong idea!"

"It could have been anyone else, it's just because you were there"

Etc.

Generally, its obvious they have feelings for someone - they're just too shy to admit it, so they cover it up with insults, physical attacks or making it seem that something isn't a big deal (even though they really think it is - like an indirect kiss for example)

When closer friends point it out, they'll often blush and stutter:

"W..what?! There's no way I could love J-Jony, where d-did you get that crazy idea from!?"