# Is Aisaka Taiga from ToraDora tsundere

Tags: toradora

ToraDora is, and most likely will be my favorite anime for a while, but I also ways am asked by my friends if I consider the character to be a tsundere. I personally don't think so because I feel that Ami, one of the other main characters, is the tsundere of the show. She's all light and fluffy to the other characters of the show until she isn't with them and she becomes all cold and distent.

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure, are you sure that's [what "tsundere" means](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26528/2516)?

Comment: Genki =/= Tsundere. Plus, Taiga is classic tsundere. The purest form of tsundere.

Comment: This is somewhat of an opinionated question.

Comment: Whenever someone says tsundere, Taiga comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Taiga is a tsundere. So much, that next to the dictionary definition of the word they printed a picture of her face.

No, this anime doesn't have any other tsunderes.